# Turn off pep8 inspections in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

This short blog says how to disable `pep8`  https://rachel-sunrui.github.io/posts/2020/04/pep8/ :

```
Go to settings, search for Inspections (Under Editor, Code style)
Find and click PEP8 code style violation. In the right panel, there is ignore errors option.
Find the error code of interest, e.g. E501 line too long here, and paste the code to Pycharm.
Ok the setting.
```

But there is no `pep8` inspection setting in `pycharm 2022.3.1` .

[image]

So how can this be done? I am on `Pycharm Professional 2022.3.1`

Comment: I have it. Did you try with the search function in the setting? (I have "PEP 8 coding style violation" and "PEP 8 naming convention violation").

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes I had tried the search, no hit on pep8/PEP8

Comment: I have the professional edition, but I surprised if it makes difference. Maybe there is a settings which hide other settings (but the search should show it)

Comment: I have `Pycharm Pro 2022.3.1` will update the post

Comment: You have the same version I have. Try to rename the configuration in your home and check again. Then check plugins. (and then copy back the important part (keyboard, colours, some preferences, etc.)